# can not install packagers in Rstudio(files missing in /usr/lib/R/etc)

Tags: 22.04, r, rstudio

I installed the R 4.3.3 version on my Ubuntu 22.04，but for some reason it didn't work, so I had to install an older version. I purged the newer version and install the *3.6.3* version with another `rstudio`, but it won't open.

It says this:

```
R shared library (/usr/local/lib/R/lib/libR.so) not found. If this is a custom build of R, was it built with the --enable-R-shlib option?
```

I deleted the source dir again and uninstalled `rstudio`, then installed the new version again (I am just a beginner). . .

Here's the point, when I open the R, it says

```
/usr/bin/R: line 249: /usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths: No such file or directory
```

"on the top,
and "uring startup - Warning message:

```
In file(file, "rt") :
cannot open file '/usr/lib/R/etc/repositories': No such file or directory
```

And when I try to install packages in studio, parts of the errors are like

```
cannot open file '/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf': No such file or directory
```

And:

```
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘data.table’ had non-zero exit status"
"installation of package ‘htmltools’ had non-zero exit status
/usr/lib/R/bin/R: line 142: /usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/R/bin/R: line 249: /usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths: No such file or directory
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection"
```

The files in my `/usr/lib/R/etc` are like in the screenshot as follows, the repositories file was created by my self and it is empty:

[image: 1]